# Correlation Coefficient $\rho(X,Y)=-1$.

Tags: probability-theory, correlation

Find an example of two variables $X,Y$ whose values are in $\{0,1\}$ s.t. $\rho(X,Y)=\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}}=-1$.

My idea is the following: I have proved through the Cauchy-Schwarz-Inequality that $|\rho(X,Y)|\leq 1$. By the inequality, equality holds iff $X$ and $Y$ are "linearly dependent". Through this idea, I, unfortunately, have only found examples of $\rho(X,Y)=1$, but not -1. Could someone help me?

Comment: take two bernulli $B\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ so that $Y=1-X$

Comment: @tommik So you are suggesting: $X: \omega\mapsto 0 $ for heads and $\omega \mapsto 1$ for tails and $Y:\omega \mapsto 0$ for tails and $1$ for tails (with a fair coin)? Works out great! Thank you!